# Why is vi6 (submediant chord in first inversion) rarely used?

Tags: theory, harmony, voice-leading, chord-inversions, functional-harmony

I read that vi6 is almost completely absent – is there a reason for this?

Comment: I’m not sure I’ve heard this rule, but it could be because it would strongly sound like the tonic chord, as the bottom two notes are the same.

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: It would be interesting to know the source and the context of the discussion.

Answer (score 5):

It’s not so much that it’s absent, as that it doesn’t really behave so much like a vi chord as like an alteration of the I chord. For example, Schenkerian analysts tend to analyze it entirely as a modification of the I, as can be seen in the recent Burststein/Straus textbook. Whenever they refer to it as a vi chord, they put it in scare quotes, like this: “vi<sup>6</sup>”.

By far the most common occurrence of a vi<sup>6</sup> chord—or, if you prefer,  a “vi<sup>6</sup>” chord—is between a I chord and a ii chord. When this happens, the fifth of the I chord moves up by step before the root and the third do the same. If one went straight from I to ii with every note moving up by step, you’d have parallel fifths, so this is a way to move one of the notes up early in order to break up the parallelism. The result might look like I–vi<sup>6</sup>–ii, but might be better though of as a 5–6 motion. In symbols: I<sup>5–6</sup>–ii.

[image: Oh no! Parallels!]

[image: Ah...Thanks 5-6!]

For example, say we’re in C Major. Going from I to ii risks parallel fifths as the C–G of the I move up by step to the D–A of the ii causing parallel fifths. If I use the 5–6 trick (or, if you prefer, interject a “vi<sup>6</sup>” chord between I and ii), then the G goes up to A *before* the C goes to D, and the bad parallel is avoided.

So, the answer to your question is that vi<sup>6</sup> is perfectly common, but many theorists think it’s more accurate to look at it as a 5–6 motion over I instead. The point is that, for the Classical composers, this was a small upper-voice movement, not a change in harmony. Here's an example from the very beginning of the first movement of Mozart's piano sonata K. 333:

[image: No parallels. Like a boss.]

Answer (score 3):

The vi6 is reasonably common in Common Practice Period pieces. It occurs in ascending sequences I-vi6-ii-vii06-iii-I6-IV-ii6. (Root position chords are more common when using this sequential technique in four part harmony.)

I found this handout on sequences on the web: http://myweb.fsu.edu/nrogers/Handouts/Diatonic_Sequence_Handout.pdf

As mentioned in the other answers, there's not a big difference in the sound, however, using a sequence allows one to proceed step by step so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

Because (using the other system of chord naming) it sounds very like I<sup>6</sup>  - the tonic chord with an added 6th.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on *how* it's used.

Two other answers already point out the `5-6` sequence.

It could also be approached with a secondary dominant to make clear it's really rooted on `vi` and not some embellishment of a `I` chord...

[image]

By comparison, if you did this...

[image]

...it sounds like it ends on a tonic chord with an added sixth, a `C6` with the fifth omitted.

Voice leading matters.